# C# basic program

Tags: c#

I have just begun learning C#. I am working on one of the first programs and I need a little help. Not sure why, but I I getting  the following error when trying to compile my code: <39, 48> CS0234 The type or namespace 'Event' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. Not sure the compiler is reading this wrong or I have mistyped something. Anyway, look over this and let me know what you think. Thanks!!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HelloWin
{
  public class MyForm : Form
  {
    private TextBox txtEnter;
    private Label lblDisplay;
    private Button btnOK;

    public MyForm()
    {
      this.txtEnter = new TextBox();
      this.lblDisplay = new Label();
      this.btnOK = new Button();
      this.Text = "My HelloWin App!";

      // txtEnter
      this.txtEnter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 32);
      this.txtEnter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 20);

      // lblDisplay
      this.lblDisplay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 72);
      this.lblDisplay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 128);

      // btnOk
      this.btnOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(88, 224);
      this.btnOK.Text = "OK";
      this.btnOK.Click +=
          new System.EventHandler(this.btnOK_Click); 
      // MyForm
      this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{this.txtEnter, this.lblDisplay, this.btnOK});
    }

    static void Main ()
    {
      Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.Event.Args e)
    {
      lblDisplay.Text = txtEnter.Text + "\n" + lblDisplay.Text;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's `System.EventArgs`, not `System.Event.Args`.

Comment: `namespace 'Event' does not exist in the namespace 'System'` means your first port of call is checking where you used `System.Event` and appriciated that that's not a thing (or isn't a reference in your project). I'm going to assume you do read these messages (they are very helpful things), and don't quite know how to interpret them, check out [Using Fully Qualified Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.71).aspx) and [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the second dot on System.Event`.`Args e

```
...
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
...
```